# short form of if (private case) c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, codeblocks

I'm trying to make a program that uses for cycle to continuously read and sum numbers. I have already done it , now I want to use short form of IF and it gives me compiling errors on the following line :

```
num == 0 ? break : sum += num;
```

errors :  expected primary-expression before 'break' ; expected ':' before 'break' ; I have no idea why this is happening and will be thankful if someone can explain to me.

full code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int num = 0;
        cin >> num;
        num == 0 ? break : sum += num;
    }
    cout << sum ;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the "normal" way? I don't see what making it shorter gives you

Comment: `break` is not an expression

Comment: `num == 0 ? break : sum += num;` -- One thing you should learn is to not make up your own rules for C++.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"short form of `if`"*. `if` is a statement, `?:` is an operator. They are different concepts that have different purposes in the language.